# How to run R package tests without building or installing the package?

Tags: r, unit-testing, package

`R CMD check` automatically runs tests located in `tests/` directory. However running the tests this way requires building the package first. After that `R CMD check` goes through various different sanity checks before finally reaching the tests at the end.

**Question:** Is there a way to run those tests without having to build or install the package first?

NOTE: without using `testthat` or other non-standard packages.

Comment: you could just `source` everything in the `tests/`-directory. I assume that's exactly what `testthat` would be doing in an interactive session.

Comment: @Tom I tried that but it has problems. I need to add `library(package)` to each test, and when I source it it loads the version that is installed, not the current version that is in development.

Comment: ah. So you need to generate a scenario where the package, that is under development is loaded into the workspace but not installed. This would be done by `devtools::load_all` -- or (not using non-standard packages) by sourcing all scripts in the `R/` directory and loading all dependencies. If you have for example `C`-Code, it is possible to load a binary via `dyn.load`

Comment: @Tom thanks, that gives me some ideas. Maybe I should add a small script somewhere in `tests/run/run.R` that sources all files under `R/` and then all files under `tests/` after that. But I wonder if this is how it was intended to be used, or if there is another way.

Comment: I would not recommend placing that script inside the package directory. I have my own small collection of scripts that provide me with the above mentioned functionalities (only using standard-base methods) in a separate directory (`R` package) that I use for all packages under development. Most likely, that was the motivation for developing `devtools` and `testthat`. Have a look at [http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html)

Comment: @Tom `devtools` has a `test()` function, but unfortunately it only works with `testthat`? I think this is by design, as the author seems to want to make people dependant on their packages for everything. `devtools` and `testthat` are fine, but the issue for me is that some packages I contribute to do not use them for testing. Hence why I am looking for a more general solution. I wish `devtools::test()` was more general thou.

Comment: I get that. If you want to be independent from non-base packages, you'll need to delevop your own toolbox for unit-testing that load `R` scripts from within the `R/` subdirectory, the `dll`s from the `source/` subdirectory and runs test scripts; just like `devtools` and `testthat` would. As CRAN is open access you can access the source code of the methods and lean on their implementation when developing your own toolbox

Comment: @Tom, thank you a lot for the comments. To summarise what you are saying: 1) there is no provided simpler alternative to `R CMD check` 2) One option would be to source everything under `R/` and then source everything under `tests/` 3) The general approach is that users develop their own custom functions to automate the above. In the spirit of Stack Overflow, maybe you would like to add this as an answer?

Comment: maybe you want to change the title to include "with base-R"

Comment: @Tom I don't mind using non base approach. As long as it allows me to run any tests 
 and not only the ones produced with (for example) `testthat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarise our discussion.

1. To my knowledge there is no standard alternative to `R CMD check` for unit testing provided by base R
2. Typically for unit testing, I source everything under `R/` (and dyn.load everything under `source/`) and then source everything under `tests/` (actually, I also use the `Example` sections of the help pages in the `man/` directory as test cases and compare their outcome to those from previous package versions)

I assume that these are the basic testing functionalities provided by `devtools` and `testthat`. If you expect to develop multiple packages and want to stay independent from non-base-R, I'd recommed to automate the above processes with custom scripts/packages.

I'd recomment looking into http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html.

Answer (score 2):

The "vanilla" way to test a package without

- running `R CMD check`
- destroying an existing installation
- cluttering your working directory

is to install into a temporary directory `tmp.lib` and test *that* installation in a second temporary directory `tmp.out` using `tools::testInstalledPackage`:

```r
pkg.name <- "Matrix"
pkg.root <- normalizePath(file.path("path", "to", pkg.name), mustWork = TRUE) # an absolute path (?)

tmp.lib <- tempfile()
tmp.out <- tempfile()
dir.create(tmp.lib)
dir.create(tmp.out)
owd <- setwd(tmp.out)

tools::Rcmd(c("build", pkg.root))
```

```
* checking for file '/x/y/z/path/to/Matrix/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
.
.
.
* building 'Matrix_1.5-5.tar.gz'
```

```r
list.files(tmp.out)
```

```
[1] "Matrix_1.5-5.tar.gz"
```

```r
tools::Rcmd(c("INSTALL", "-l", tmp.lib, "--install-tests", "*.tar.gz"))
```

```
* installing *source* package 'Matrix' ...
.
.
.
* DONE (Matrix)
```

```r
list.files(tmp.lib)
```

```
[1] "Matrix"
```

```r
tools::testInstalledPackage(pkg.name, lib.loc = tmp.lib, types = "tests")
```

```
Running specific tests for package 'Matrix'
  Running 'Class+Meth.R'
  Running 'Simple.R'
  Running 'abIndex-tsts.R'
  Running 'base-matrix-fun.R'
  Running 'bind.R'
  comparing 'bind.Rout' to 'bind.Rout.save' ... OK
  Running 'dg_Matrix.R'
  Running 'dpo-test.R'
  Running 'dtpMatrix.R'
  Running 'factorizing.R'
  Running 'group-methods.R'
  Running 'indexing.R'
  comparing 'indexing.Rout' to 'indexing.Rout.save' ... OK
  Running 'matprod.R'
  Running 'matr-exp.R'
  Running 'other-pkgs.R'
  Running 'packed-unpacked.R'
  Running 'spModel.matrix.R'
  Running 'symmDN.R'
  Running 'validObj.R'
  Running 'write-read.R'
```

```r
list.files(tmp.out, recursive = TRUE)
```

```
 [1] "Matrix-tests/Class+Meth.R"         "Matrix-tests/Class+Meth.Rout"     
 [3] "Matrix-tests/Rplots.pdf"           "Matrix-tests/Simple.R"            
 [5] "Matrix-tests/Simple.Rout"          "Matrix-tests/abIndex-tsts.R"      
 [7] "Matrix-tests/abIndex-tsts.Rout"    "Matrix-tests/base-matrix-fun.R"   
 [9] "Matrix-tests/base-matrix-fun.Rout" "Matrix-tests/bind.R"              
[11] "Matrix-tests/bind.Rout"            "Matrix-tests/bind.Rout.save"      
[13] "Matrix-tests/dg_Matrix.R"          "Matrix-tests/dg_Matrix.Rout"      
[15] "Matrix-tests/dpo-test.R"           "Matrix-tests/dpo-test.Rout"       
[17] "Matrix-tests/dtpMatrix.R"          "Matrix-tests/dtpMatrix.Rout"      
[19] "Matrix-tests/factorizing.R"        "Matrix-tests/factorizing.Rout"    
[21] "Matrix-tests/group-methods.R"      "Matrix-tests/group-methods.Rout"  
[23] "Matrix-tests/indexing.R"           "Matrix-tests/indexing.Rout"       
[25] "Matrix-tests/indexing.Rout.save"   "Matrix-tests/matprod.R"           
[27] "Matrix-tests/matprod.Rout"         "Matrix-tests/matr-exp.R"          
[29] "Matrix-tests/matr-exp.Rout"        "Matrix-tests/mm-Matrix.tab"       
[31] "Matrix-tests/other-pkgs.R"         "Matrix-tests/other-pkgs.Rout"     
[33] "Matrix-tests/packed-unpacked.R"    "Matrix-tests/packed-unpacked.Rout"
[35] "Matrix-tests/spModel.matrix.R"     "Matrix-tests/spModel.matrix.Rout" 
[37] "Matrix-tests/symmDN.R"             "Matrix-tests/symmDN.Rout"         
[39] "Matrix-tests/validObj.R"           "Matrix-tests/validObj.Rout"       
[41] "Matrix-tests/write-read.R"         "Matrix-tests/write-read.Rout"     
[43] "Matrix_1.5-5.tar.gz"
```

```r
setwd(owd)
unlink(tmp.out)
unlink(tmp.lib)
```

Of course, you would want to put all of that into a function, ideally with an option to *not* destroy the output directory so that you can inspect the `.Rout` files and any `.Rout.fail` files as needed.